# Inserting bullet points into my div moves it to the left

Tags: css, html, containers

In my .css, I'm using a fixed width, centered layout with:

`#page-container {
      width: 760px;
      margin: auto;
      padding-top: 10px;
    }`

All pages using the .css are the same width. If I insert bullet points into a `div`, it seems to move to the left by a few pixels and is no longer centered. This also happens if I insert an `iframe`.

Perhaps someone more experienced could suggest the cause?

**[Edit]**

It's being caused by the scrollbar appearing as I add content. Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Kinda difficult to diagnose without seeing the html markup, but could it perhaps be the appearance of a scrollbar that's causing the shift when you add content?

Comment: do you make good use of the f12 developer tools in the browsers?  go find that ul element and see what styles are applied to it - then you can mess with margins and padding live and see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the page from shifting, you should set the body style to overflow:scroll so there's always a scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably seeing is the default margin and padding of `ul` and `li` elements.

Use a web developer tool such as Firebug and hover over the element, you'll see the margins and paddings.

For example a `ul` element has some default margin (*in yellow*) and padding (*in purple*):

[image]

What you can do is apply CSS to reset those defaults:

```
ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul li { margin 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks - I havn't defined any margin or padding for <ul> or <li> so that would make sense. How could I specify this?

Comment: @James: Do you see the CSS I typed in? That fixes the problem you're having by giving both elements zero margin and padding.

Comment: Thanks very much - I gave it a try, but it's not the effect I need. It turns out the problem is caused by the scrollbar appearing when I add content. Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: In that case, we need HTML in your original question. Edit your question and add it in.